# What signal does Intellij use to terminate tests?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I am running some cucumber tests (ruby-based) in Intellij-14 on windows 7. There are times that I want to stop execution of the tests early, but I still want all the cleanup that happens in the cucumber at_exit block to take place. My solution to this was the following code:

```
trap 'SIGINT' do
  cleanup 
  exit 130
end
```

It does ensure cleanup takes place upon receiving ctrl+c, but if I am running in Intellij and I stop execution (button is called "stop process"), cleanup does not occur.

What signal does Intellij use to stop running processes? Alternatively, how can I ensure cleanup takes place for every signal?

Answer (score 0):

is there anything preventing you from doing cleanup before the tests? this way you don't have to worry about all signals, and if things are left in an inconsistent state because intellij killed it it's still okay.

Orthogonal to this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html
Normally you want to handle: 15 (TERM), 1 (HUP), 2 (INT)

Comment: I am cleaning up resources that I have created to run the tests, so it is not possible to clean it up beforehand. I will look into the resource/suggestions you provided.

Comment: TERM and INT did not trap whatever intellij used to end the process, and HUP netted me a "unsupported signal SIGHUP (ArgumentError)", which from my googling leads me to believe that it is not supported on Windows.

Comment: ha! probably should have included that it's windows in question. is there anything preventing you from doing cleanup before the tests?

Comment: I realize that now =P. Yes, the materials I am cleaning are used within the tests, so I cannot clean it up before they run.